# How to have a dropdownlist within a listview and bind it dynamically in .Net C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am building a Ecommerce website where in i have multiple products with same name
i.e. for example i have got two products

1. Rice 20KG
2. Rice 10KG

I do have this saved in database as below:

```
Product Id  Name  Weight GroupId

1           Rice  20KG   Null
2           Rice  10KG   1
```

i.e these two products are related and the groupid identifies the group,and hence if i have one more item as rice it wold be:

```
3           Rice  5KG   1
```

now i am haing a problem in displaying this on the webpage

1. display all the items  which has groupid as NULL.
2. i need dropdown list in each product which lists down the different weights

and when i select the weight the product id in the listview should change

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please share with us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Hi, i have created a list view where i am using sql datasource which has query to list items which has group id as null, now i am finding it difficut to implement rest of the things

Comment: Ok, that's a good start! Next you need the DropDownList to list the weights. You could have another query for that - where the product ID = x or the group ID = x. That should get you the list of weights, no?